# permission in SP

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have my sql auth user, which has Insert access to table A in database A.

I have my team’s sql user, which has read access to table B in database B.

I need to create a SP, that will select from table B in database B and insert it in table A in database A. (and should run daily …)

- What’s the most professional approach? I don’t want to use EXECUTE AS…
- I also don’t understand… if the SP by default gets executed with the caller’s permission, the caller would be sql agent, so in the SP I could be dropping all the databases?! (what am I missing?)
- if it gets executed with the creator permissions, is it executed with the creators permission at the moment of creation or at the current moment of execution?!

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you how I do similar things currently.  We will have a Active Directory service account set up with the needed access, be it DBO, sys admin or data Writer.  Create a job to run the script in question and the Job will use the SQL Agent's user ID or whatever account you designate.

Our SQL agent account has the needed permissions to run any jobs that are needed on the server and works the easiest for us.  You only have to set it up once and then use that account for all jobs.